# KVM module is not loaded in container

Tags: docker, virtualization, kvm

I am running a Linux container on my windows laptop.
Container is running CentOS 7.4.1708.
Laptop is running Windows 10 Enterprise version 1709 build 16299

The problem:
I can not load KVM module inside the container.
modprobe command is failing without any message and there is nothing in dmesg.
I looked in Linuxkit kernel config files, kvm is there with the loadable module option (m).

I enabled virtualization in the laptop bios and also enabled nested virtualization in the MobyLinuxVM in Hyper-V (I used the below manual)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization

I am using the following command to run the container:

```
docker run -d --net=host --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --privileged --security-opt seccomp:unconfined -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -it centos:latest /usr/sbin/init

docker exec -it  f1772f2e66c0  /bin/bash
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I have the same issue. Waiting for experts...